# two consecutive "cudaMallocPitch" make the code failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nsight

I wrote a simple CUDA code as follows:

```
//Allocate the first 2d array "deviceArray2DInput"
if(cudaMallocPitch((Float32**) &deviceArray2DInput, &devicePitch, sizeof(Float32)*deviceColNumber,deviceRowNumber) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation){
    return -1;
}

//Allocate the second 2d array "deviceArray2DOutput". It was suppose to hold the output of some process.
if(cudaMallocPitch((Float32**) &deviceArray2DOutput, &devicePitch,sizeof(Float32)*deviceRowNumber,deviceColNumber) == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation){
    return -1;
}

//Copy data from "hostArrayR" to "deviceArray2DInput" (#1)
cudaMemcpy2D(deviceArray2DInput,devicePitch,hostArrayR,sizeof(Float32)*colNumber,sizeof(Float32)*deviceColNumber,deviceRowNumber,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//Clean the top 10000 elements in "hostArrayR" for verification. 
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    hostArrayR[i] = 0;
}

//Copy data back from "deviceArray2DInput" to "hostArrayR"(#2)
cudaMemcpy2D(hostArrayR,sizeof(Float32)*colNumber,deviceArray2DInput,devicePitch,sizeof(Float32)*deviceColNumber,deviceRowNumber,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

I commented out the second allocation block, the code worked well. It copied the data from the host array "hostArrayR" to the device array "deviceArray2DInput" and copied it back. **However, if both allocation blocks existed, the copied-back "hostArrayR" was empty (no data was copyed back from device).**

I am sure that the data was in "hostArrayR" at line (#1) but there was no data at line (#2). I cleaned the first 10000 elements (much lesss than the size of the array) to verfy that data did not come back.

I am using Nvidia Nsight 2.2 on Visual Studio 2010. The array size is 1024x768 and I am using floating 32-bit data. My GPU card is GTX570. It seems that there was no memory allocation error (or the code will return before doing copy stuffs).

I did not try "cudaMalloc()" because I prefer to use "cudaMallocPitch()" for memory alignment.

Comment: You error checking looks rather fragile to me. What if an error other than `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation` is returned? And the `cudaMemcpy2D()`s have no error checks at all. I'd recommend to consistently check that all return codes are equal to `cudaSuccess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should check the API calls against cudaSuccess, rather than one
  specific error.
- You should check the error value returned by the memcpys.
- You're overwriting the `devicePitch` on the second `cudaMallocPitch()` call, the arrays have different shapes and hence could have different pitches.

Comment: I rewrote the code: (1)against "cudaSuccess" (2) use two separate "devicePitch" (I think you are right, the "devicePitch" was overwritten by the second allocation block and it caused the memory copy failed, which was not checked in my original code). Now it works well. Thank you.